# Qt 5.1: QMultimedia 5.0 in android for Camera

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I want to use camera in Android with Qml interface and QtMultimedia 5.0
Until now I haven't succeeded in it.

I'm using Qt 5.1 with qtquick 2.1 and Android 4.2.2 API 17

Here is my code:

main.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 1280
    color:'green'

    Camera {
        id: camera
        imageCapture {
            onImageCaptured: {
                // Show the preview in an Image
                photoPreview.source = preview
            }
            onImageSaved: {
                text.text = qsTr("Last Captured Image (%1):").arg(camera.imageCapture.capturedImagePath)
            }
        }
    }
    Column {
        Text {
            height: 15
            text: qsTr("Preview (Click to capture):")
        }
        VideoOutput {
            source: camera
            focus: visible // To receive focus and capture key events when visible
            width: 320; height: 240
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: camera.imageCapture.capture()
            }
        }
        Text {
            id: text
            height: 15
            text: qsTr("Last Captured Image (none)")
        }
        Image {
            id: photoPreview
            width: 320; height: 240
        }
    }
}
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml file I added:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

What I got is white screen

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have a HTC device, this bug could be the reason why you get no video output: [QTBUG-43487](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-43487).

Comment: I have simulated it in a virtual device